# Copying MySQL database from server to local machine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Currently I've got a working MySQL database on a GoDaddy's server however, I'd like to copy it (the database schema + data) to a local Windows machine and access it via MySQL Workbench.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1487/exporting-a-mysql-database-from-your-hosting-account

Comment: Small: `mysqldump`. Large: ... depends on what GoDaddy offers, I don't assume they provide you with the access & tooling required to use `xtrabackup`...

Comment: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases

Comment: Please put further suggestions into the community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1487/… –  ForguesR 15 mins ago

Small: mysqldump. Large: ... depends on what GoDaddy offers, I don't assume they provide you with the access & tooling required to use xtrabackup... –  Wrikken 14 mins ago
    upvote
    flag

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/… –  Chris Lear 14 mins ago